# Updating prime number via javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, primes

I tried to update the prime number onthe fly using javascript without using serverside coding.
Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>AJAX with PHP: Quickstart</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var n = 1;
search: while (true) {
  n += 1;
  for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 1)
    if (n % i == 0)
     continue search;
  // found a prime!
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=n;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p> I want to update prime number here</p>

<div id="result" >

</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

However, div "result" is not updated here. Can't we do this with only javascript?
Like this in following example http://www.whatwg.org/demos/workers/primes/page.html

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>AJAX with PHP: Quickstart</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var n = 1;
function testNextPrime() {
    var isPrime = true;
    n = n + 1;
   // console.log('testing', n);
    for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 1) {
        if (n % i == 0) isPrime = false;
    }

    if (isPrime) {
       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=n;
      }

    // Schedule the next test (this gives browser a chance to update display and process any other events)
    setTimeout(testNextPrime, 2000);
}
// Start testing for primes
testNextPrime();
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p> I want to update prime number here</p>

<div id="result" >

</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whoa, using labels in JS???  In 15 years of writing JS, I have yet to see any real-world code that uses labels.  I'm not even sure how they're supposed to work in conjunction with `while` loops like this.

Comment: What's the real purpose of this? It appears to be an infinite loop! change "while(true)" to something like "while(n < 100)" to get the highest prime number under 100, for example.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you have an infinite loop.  You never exit the `while (true) ...` loop?  Until that happens, the browser never has an opportunity to update the DOM and refresh the display.

Here's a [JSFiddle showing one way to use setTimeout()](http://jsfiddle.net/dASfc/3/) to relinquish control to the main event loop.

Update: You can use web workers, but that requires breaking the worker code out into a script that can be loaded from a separate URL.  [Doing this in a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tokkonoPapa/53KEJ/) is possible but requires some contortions that make the solution a little more complicated than otherwise necessary.   So just be aware of that when reading that code.

Comment: Can't we implement it like this demonostation. here webworkers technology is used http://www.whatwg.org/demos/workers/primes/page.html

Comment: Uh, no, because that demo page appears to have the same problem. (locks up that browser tab due, I expect, to there being an infinite loop.)

Comment: That said, yes, this *problem* would be a good use case for web workers, but you definitely need to implement such that you avoid the infinite loop issue.

Comment: see 2nd jsfiddle link above for example using web workers (not my code, btw, I just happened to stumble across it while googling)

Comment: I updated my code to yours but I want to update the prime in ` if (isPrime) {
          document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=n;
    }` But it doesnt print the prime in result div, though it prints jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you're not seeing the prime update periodically in the `html` section of that jsfiddle page?

Comment: I have updated the code. which I got from yours but it doesn't work in the browser. To work I need to replace document.write(n) but it prints all the primes.I need to show only the latest one.

Comment: 'not sure how to help with this.  The only document.write call is in a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
// found a prime!
    document.write(n);
```

Keep in mind, that your loop is infinite and browser most likely will crash at some point.